# Is it possible to install macOS and Windows 10 on same external SSD?

Tags: mac, windows, usb, ssd

Is there anyway to install macOS Sierra and Windows 10 on external SSD drive?

I bought a new T3 250GB Samsung external USB 3 drive.

I want to install macOS on 100GB partition and Windows 10 on other 100GB partition for max speed on all OSes .

Bootcamp only offers internal HDD drive of my iMac and Windows 10 can't install on the USB drive without formatting the whole disk and which I will lose all partitions like the macOS partition .

Comment: If you install macOS with the full 250GB, you can use an app like [Parallels](http://www.parallels.com/ca/) or [VMWare Fusion](https://www.vmware.com/products/fusion.html) to run Windows 10 on a virtually drive, which can be partitioned to be 100 GB. This OS can run full screen, and doesn’t require drivers because it is being run in a Virtual Machine.

Comment: Why would you want to do this when USB is inherently slower than SATA?  See [this post](https://apple.stackexchange.com/questions/294917/are-loading-times-using-a-usb-hard-drive-slower/294987#294987)  for more info.

Comment: @Allan t3 ssd drive now on my mac have write 350 mb and read 420 mb so run apps absolutely faster than internal hdd.

Comment: @bret7600 this is the end way if someone dose not have any idea!